# Invert Map with list value Map<Key, List<Value>> to Map <Value, Key> in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map kind of grouping values by key `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, i want to revert in order to map each value to the corresponding key

Example: I want to transform the code below

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> mapOfIntList = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

mapOfIntList.put("UNIT", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 0, 8, 6));
mapOfIntList.put("TEN", Arrays.asList(24, 90, 63, 87));
mapOfIntList.put("HUNDRED", Arrays.asList(645, 457, 306, 762));
mapOfIntList.put("THOUSAND", Arrays.asList(1234, 3456, 5340, 9876));
```

to another Map(Integer, String) where i can find :
(1, "UNIT"), (2, "UNIT")...(24, "TEN"), (90, "TEN")...(645, "HUNDRED")...(3456, "THOUSAND")...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

```
Map<Integer, String> mapNumberToType = mapOfIntList.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,e)->e.getValue().forEach(v->m.put(v,e.getKey())), Map::putAll);
```

You may recognize the similarity to the `forEach` based code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113793/2711488) within the second function passed to `collect` (the accumulator) function. For a sequential execution, they do basically the same, but this Stream solution supports parallel processing. That’s why it needs the other two functions, to support creating local containers and to merge them.

See also the [Mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) section of the documentation.

Comment: Works great !... Thanks !

Comment: @Holger, What changes need to supports parallel processing?

Comment: @HadiJ None. That’s the point. The two nested `forEach` are simpler whereas this `collect` based solution supports parallel processing.

Comment: what if my values are not unique? `mapOfIntList.put("UNIT", Arrays.asList(1, 2)); mapOfIntList.put("TEN", Arrays.asList(2, 90));` With code above, I would get among others `2=TEN` instead of `2=[UNIT, TEN]`. Can the script be altered to also handle non unique values?

Answer (score 6):

Or use two nested `forEach`

```
mapOfIntList.forEach((key, value) ->
            value.forEach(v -> {
                mapNumberToType.put(v, key);
            })
 );
```

as @nullpointer commented in one-liner

```
mapOfIntList.forEach((key, value) -> value.forEach(v -> mapNumberToType.put(v, key)));
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution :

```
Map<Integer, String> mapNumberToType = mapOfIntList
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(
            entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                    .map(number -> Pair.of(number, entry.getKey()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream())
    .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Pair::getLeft,
                    Pair::getRight, (a, b) -> {
                        return a;
                    }));

System.out.println("Number/Type correspondance : " + mapNumberToType);
```

hope this helps anyone having the same problem !

Comment: The last collect could be simplifies as :`.collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getLeft, Pair::getRight));`

Comment: @nullpointer Well, only if you guarantee there will be no duplicate values. Also the `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` in the `flatMap()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @DidierL what would be the correct behavior in case of duplicates here?

Comment: @DidierL I used at the first time the second map without collecting and then streaming, but it doesn't work, the compiler doesn't detect the object types after this stage

Comment: @Holger That depends on the OP's requirements, who also wrote this answer. However that simplification wouldn't be equivalent to the original code.

Comment: @Shessuky It seems to work in Aomine's answer (with `SimpleEntry` instead of `Pair`)

Answer (score 4):

This would be simpler as:

```
 source.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, e.getKey())))
       .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (l, r) -> l));
```

Comment: Just tested, i have encounter a problem : The method toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, (<no type> l, <no type> r) -> {}) is undefined for the type DateParser. Do i miss something ?

Comment: where did you get `DateParser` from? I've tested this against the provided data in your post. see [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/XNnVZp) for a working example.

Comment: I have checked the code in ideone, then created a class with the same code, but i have got an error on all the stream with the message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Integer,String>, i'll dig into this...thanks a lot !